# How to create Type-Constrained Interfaces and Factory functions for them in Golang?

Tags: go

I have the following interfaces

```golang
package binaryutils

type BinaryEncoder [T any]interface {
    Encode(d T) []byte
}
```

I have the following structs that implement them.

```golang
type StringEncoder struct{}
type Float64Encoder struct{}
type BoolEncoder struct{}

func (e *StringEncoder) Encode(s string) []byte {
    return []byte(s)
}

func (e *Float64Encoder) Encode(f float64) []byte {
    buf := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf, math.Float64bits(f))
    return buf
}

func (e *BoolEncoder) Encode(b bool) []byte {
    if b {
        return []byte{1}
    } else {
        return []byte{0}
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing here is that my Factory function:

```golang
func BinaryEncoderFactory(dataType string) (BinaryEncoder, error) {
    switch dataType {
    case "string":
        return StringEncoder{}, nil
    case "float64":
        return Float64Encoder{}, nil
    case "boolean":
        return BoolEncoder{}, nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("invalid data type")
    }
}
```

Throws this error: "cannot use generic type BinaryEncoder[T any] without instantiation compiler(WrongTypeArgCount)" at the Function Declaration

How can I fix this?

I want:

1. Compile time type checking
2. The ability to abstract behind an BinaryEncoder interface

I am new to the idea of Factories, and Dependency injections so please help me understand the philosophy behind them. Thanks.

Comment: Type parameters must be resolved at compile time, you are using them to compile type-specialized code after all. You can't return a `BinaryEncoder` without the actual type it needs to compile.

Comment: Right, for now I feel like I will have to give up one of the two desires I expressed above (Type Checking and Abstraction). Or do you think there could be a workaround?

Comment: Generics do not replace normal interface usage, invert the argument and use an interface with methods like in the `json` package for example

Comment: Your `BinaryEncoderFactory` requires a string argument to describe the type at runtime, but you are asking for compile-time type safety which means you must know the type at compile time. Maybe start with something like: https://go.dev/play/p/dvZWtnlJzJh

Comment: Hmmm this seems like good middle ground. But I had a question, in this style the Encoder seems to be tightly coupled with the Data it is encoding. Does that not seem weird or unusual?

Comment: The data _is_ the encoder in this example, it encodes itself, so the coupling is kind of irrelevant. It's not unusual, it's the basically the same pattern used by [`json.Marshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshaler).

Comment: I see. I am beginning to see that the type safety is something I DON"T want. For example. If the encoding logic is to be abstracted out so that it can be used in cases like a dependency injection, generics will work against me for such cases. Take a look here: https://go.dev/play/p/CVicqly0rBw. Keeping injections in mind, do you think any other method is better?

Comment: I would first question the requirement for dependency injection at all. It's not relied on in Go like some other languages. If it helps, yet another pattern can be seen in this msgpack library, where the general interface always takes a concrete encoder instance which defines the protocol: [`msgpack.CustomEncoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/v5#CustomEncoder)

Answer (score 0):

The source of your specific error is that your factory function is returning a `BinaryEncoder` without specifying the type parameter that the generic `BinaryEncoder` type requires.

Trying to fix this with your current approach is difficult, if not impossible, since your various `...Encoder{}` types do not implement the generic `BinaryEncoder[T]` interface.

They *do* implement a specific instantation of that interface:

```
StringEncoder   implements BinaryEncoder[String]
Float64Encoder  implements BinaryEncoder[float64]
BoolEncoder     implements BinaryEncoder[bool]
```

From this it should be apparent that a single function that could return any of these types cannot do so in a type-safe manner.  afaict it could only be achieved by returning `any` since all of the possible return values are of different types and implement different interfaces.

However, a small change to the `BinaryEncoder` interface *does* make this possible.

You need all of your encoders to be compatible with a single type, which may then be the return type of your factory function.  This could be achieved by removing the value to be encoded from the argument list of the `Encode()` function of the interface:

```golang
type BinaryEncoder interface {
   Encode() []byte
}
```

Your encoders then capture the value to be encoded.  I'll use an anonymous field:

```golang
type StringEncoder struct{ string }
type Float64Encoder struct{ float64 }
type BoolEncoder struct{ bool }
```

The implementation of the `Encode()` function for these types then needs a minor change to reference the field of the receiver instead of an argument to the function:

```golang
func (e *StringEncoder) Encode() []byte {
    return []byte(e.string)
}

func (e *Float64Encoder) Encode() []byte {
    buf := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf, math.Float64bits(e.float64))
    return buf
}

func (e *BoolEncoder) Encode() []byte {
    if e.bool {
        return []byte{1}
    } else {
        return []byte{0}
    }
}
```

And finally, the `BinaryEncoderFactory` can be modified to bring all this together by accepting a value to be encoded rather than a string identifying the type.  A type-switch in the factory then ensures that the right encoder is returned and initialised with the value supplied:

```golang
func NewBinaryEncoder(v any) (BinaryEncoder, error) {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case string:
        return &StringEncoder{v}, nil
    case float64:
        return &Float64Encoder{v}, nil
    case bool:
        return &BoolEncoder{v}, nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("invalid data type")
    }
}
```

As a finesse, the function is renamed as `NewBinaryEncoder`, which I believe is more idiomatic Go.

The full solution is in [this Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/FAXBCM_rBn6).

### Downside...

A disadvantage of the above solution is that every value you wish to encode involves a new encoder rather than being able to re-use a single encoder for all values of a given type.

If that's a problem, then you will need to find a different approach.

It's also worth pointing out that since the encoders returned by the factory are now "one-shot" encoders, only good for encoding the value supplied to the factory and nothing else, then instead of returning the encoder the factory could instead return the `[]byte` that the encoder would itself return since, presumably, the returned encoder is only going to be used to .. encode these bytes!

The factory function is then not a factory function at all but a helper which simply selects an encoder appropriate to encode some supplied value based on its type and does the encoding for you using that encoder.

Another, simpler, option might be to abandon the use of the factory function entirely and use your encoders when and as required... if the code consuming this factory knows enough to specify what type of encoder to ask for (in the `dataType` parameter) then it presumably knows enough to determine which encoder to use and doesn't need to delegate this to a factory with an instruction as to the choice to be made.

i.e. instead of:

```golang
   enc, _ := BinaryEncoderFactory("string") // < we KNOW it's a string
   b := enc.Encode("encode me")
```

simply:

```golang
   enc, _ := &StringEncoder{}
   b := enc.Encode("encode me")
```

And if we're doing this, then instead of a new encoder every time, we can initialise our encoders up front and then select the appropriate one as needed:

```golang
   // declared elsewhere in the package
   var stringEncoder = &StringEncoder{}

   // then in use...
   b := stringEncoder.Encode("encode me")
```

Without a clearer understanding of the context in which your factory and associated types are to be used, it's difficult to say for certain which of these options is the best approach; it's entirely possible that some other approach would be better/more appropriate than any of those presented.